# Spring: Attaching @Qualifer to Java-configured beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

In spring, you can XML-configure a bean to have a qualifier. I can't seem to find how I can attach a qualifier if configuring beans through Java annotations. What's up with that? Do I have to use just plain old names?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you're using annotations (not Java based configuration), you can use the following to add a qualifier (see the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-qualifiers)):

```
@Component
@Qualifier("myQualifier")
public class MyBean {
    //code
}
```

And to wire in the bean, use the following (again, see the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)):

```
public class MyClass {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myQualifier")
    private MyBean myBean;

    //more code

}
```

Comment: And what's wrong with `@Component("componentName")`? How `@Component @Qualifier` is better?

Comment: @Nick You can qualify multiple components with the same qualifier. Think of it as a grouping concept.

Answer (score 19):

What, like `@Qualifier`, you mean?

[3.10.4 Defining bean metadata within components](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factorybeans-annotations)

Example:

```
  @Bean @Qualifier("public")
  public TestBean publicInstance() {
      return new TestBean("publicInstance");
  }
```

Comment: +1. See also my answer for autowiring (didn't add it here b/c code would be hard to read).