# Spring factory - NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException:

Tags: spring

I am trying to implement factory pattern to get producer from a list of available ones. While doing it i am getting the below exception. Not able to figure out the issue with the code. Can you please let me know what i am missing.

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.test.interfaces.Producer] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: A,B

Please find the code below

```
    public interface Producer<T>  {
    public void start();
    public List<T> produce() throws CEHServiceException;
    public void stop();
}

@Component("A")
public class ProducerA extends Producer  {
    //Autowire Services & Properties

}

@Component("B")
public class ProducerB extends Producer  {
    //Autowire Services & Properties
}

@Configuration
public class AgentConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ServiceLocatorFactoryBean createProducerFactoryBean(){
        ServiceLocatorFactoryBean bean = new ServiceLocatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setServiceLocatorInterface(ProducerFactory.class);
        return bean;
    }
}

public interface ProducerFactory {

    Producer getProducer(String producerName);

}

@Component
public class AdvancedAgentProcessor {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectFactory<AdvancedRunnerImpl> runnerFactory;
    public void init(){
        AdvancedRunnerImpl runner = runnerFactory.getObject();
        runner.setProducerName("A");
        runner.start();
    }

}


@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class AdvancedRunnerImpl implements Runner {

    @Autowired private ProducerFactory producerFactory;
    private Producer producer;
    private String producerName;

    public void start() {
        producer = producerFactory.getProducer(this.producerName);
    }

}
```

Full stack tracke

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.test.etl.interfaces.Producer] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: A,B
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:365)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ServiceLocatorFactoryBean$ServiceLocatorInvocationHandler.invokeServiceLocatorMethod(ServiceLocatorFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ServiceLocatorFactoryBean$ServiceLocatorInvocationHandler.invoke(ServiceLocatorFactoryBean.java:363)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getProducer(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.runner.AdvancedRunnerImpl.start(AdvancedRunnerImpl.java:54)
    at com.test.app.AdvancedAgentProcessor.init(AdvancedAgentProcessor.java:48)
    at com.test.app.DataAgentApplication.main(DataAgentApplication.java:25)
```

Comment: What is your ProducerFactory implementation?

Comment: Is anything else in your `ApplicationContext` trying to autowire an instance of a single `Producer` anywhere?  Can you provide the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @gabrielgiussi it is a dynamic proxy that Spring will create based on the presence of the `ServiceLocatorFactoryBean`.  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ServiceLocatorFactoryBean.html

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild Had updated the post with stack trace. I am using spring boot 1.2.7 and i don't use ApplicationContext directly anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring does not know which component to autowire. It seems that the problem is in the ProducerFactoryImplementation but we cannot see it.

There are three possible solutions:

1. Use Qualifiers so you can tell Spring which specific implementation you want.There is an example in StackOverflow
   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9183185/16206)
2. Use the [Primary](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) annotation (See more here[3](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-primary)). That means that in case of ambiguity Spring will give priority to the @Primary annotated component
3. Autowire a list of beans. Something like:

   ```
   @Autowired private List<Producer> myAvalilableProducers;

   public Producer getByName(name){

       for( Producer producer: myAvalilableProducers){
           if(producer.getName().equals(name)){ return producer; }
       }
       throw new RuntimeException("No producer with name " + name " found");
   }
   ```

This third option more useful when you do not know the specific instance at compile time or if you really want to inject a list of components.

Comment: This works. But introduces two issues, i need to introduce a new field called producer name and any new producers i add will need to change the code in Runner. i will go ahead and implement it. Thanks.

Comment: You my avoid the name field by using the qualifiers like in the example I have just linked. Or you could use getClass().getAnnnotation(Qualifier.class).vale instead of name

Answer (score 0):

You have two beans that extend Producer. Somewhere you are trying to autowire a Producer. Spring does not know which Producer to use.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the dynamic proxy is not able to pick the correct Bean. Please check whether `this.producerName` is null or empty.